# writing specific lines from one file to another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I'm trying to read a file, look for a specific word and if a line contains that word, remove the line and send the remaining lines to a new file.
Here's what I have but it is only finding one of the lines not all of them;

```
with open('letter.txt') as l:
  for lines in l:
    if not lines.startswith("WOOF"):
      with open('fixed.txt', 'w')as f:
        print(lines.strip(), file=f)
```

Comment: Please tag the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `with open('fixed.txt', 'w') as f:` you basically [overwrite the entire content of the file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) with that one next line. Either open the file in *append* mode `a` ...

```
with open('letter.txt') as l:
    for lines in l:
        if not lines.startswith("WOOF"):
            with open('fixed.txt', 'a') as f:
                print(lines.strip(), file=f)
```

... or (probably better) open the file in `w` mode, but just once at the beginning:

```
with open('letter.txt') as l, open('fixed.txt', 'w') as f:
    for lines in l:
        if not lines.startswith("WOOF"):
            print(lines.strip(), file=f)
```